# "Similarly to" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: expressions

I have a follow up question to using "Similarly to" at the beginning of a sentence.

["similarly to" in the sentence beginning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163990/similarly-to-in-the-sentence-beginning)
suggests to use "As in".

Does "as in" mean "equally" or just "similar to"?

Example sentence:
"Similarly to DSST, we only use the first 27-channels of the FHOG feature map appended with a gray-scale image for the translational filter of DSSTcpp."

"As in the DSST tracker, we only use the first 27-channels of the FHOG feature map appended with a gray-scale image for the translational filter of DSSTcpp."

The sentence should reflect a similarity, but DSSTcpp is not euqal to DSST.

Thanks
myro

Comment: 'As in' only works with certain sentences. 'As is the case with ...' overlaps far more closely with 'Like ...'.

Answer (score 1):

"As in" doesn't necessarily mean the two things being compared are equals, but it can convey that. The [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/as) of "as": to the same degree, amount, or extent; similarly; equally. So when using "as in", you are essentially saying "[to the same or similar degree] *in* the DSST tracker".

Answer (score -1):

The phrase you are looking for is **just as**.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of what "as in" means - and the asker is looking for something that means similar. I would think "just as" would mean equal to.